# Invalid Value HardhatConfig.networks.local.accounts

Tags: ethereumjs, hardhat

While executing the following command `npx hardhat node --fork`, I recieve the following error. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: error]

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value 7.78145173254702e+76 for HardhatConfig.networks.local.accounts - Expected a value of type "remote" | string[] | HttpNetworkHDAccountsConfig | undefined.

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/
```

Comment: that's really hard to read. can you copy & paste the text in formatted as code, plus your hardhat config

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The error I was getting was due to the wrong initialization of the private key in `accounts` field of hardhat.config.js file.
Initially I was declaring it as:

```
local: {
  url: LOCAL_URL,      
  accounts: 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80
}
```

The correct declaration would be

```
accounts: ['0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80']
```